# List usb dvb devices with device name

Tags: usb, dvb

I have 7 USB DVB-C devices of which one of them is isn't working correctly. I'm trying to find out which one it is without enabling/disabling them one by one. In TVHeadend it is only list as /dev/dvb/adapter0(-6) and the device chipset is shown. Now I have different devices using the same chipset. I know of lsusb to list usb devices and lsdvb to list dvb devices. lsusb gives me the actual device name but not which dvb adapter it is. lsdvb shows me all the adapters but not the device name (eg: Technisat Cablestar, Terratec etc).

Is there one command to see all info, or multiple commands which still enables me to see what device is which adapter?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Research indicates that [dvbsnoop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dvbsnoop&searchon=names) might be helpful in troubleshooting your issue.  Another thought would be to utilize the `-v` verbose switches on the programs mentioned to see if you get more useful information that way. I don't have any of teh devices in question for testing, so if this doesn't help you have my apologies.

Comment: `lsusb` provides the `-v` option for verbose output, which displays really every information you might need. Maybe also useful – and much more clear – is the option `-t`, which displays the devices in a neat tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with the two following commands i'm able to find the information needed:

```
ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*
```

list all USB devices

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
```

Show device names in the order of the list above.